# using the right word - dismantle or disassembling a fitted object

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, differences, antonyms, speech

I am confused about using dismantling and disassembling when it comes to furniture like door or chair. Can we say we dismantle a door or disassemble a door or simply broke them apart,pull it out or something else?
Machines are usually dismantled. A fitted thing is not dismantled or disassembled?

Example

if the door itself was broken into smaller pieces, can we use any one word or should we use words like broken into or taken apart.For example a child may ask - can the fitted pieces of wood be taken apart or pulled out to be used again - although it may not be possible - how will I explain it to him?

Comment: Although the terms are reasonably close synonyms, 'disassemble' carries at least a strong sense that the parts will be kept safe, ready for reassembly. 'Dismantle' has a hint of a cruder approach (if not a demolition job). // Though I can't find dictionary support, contributors at [Proz.com](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english/construction-civil-engineering/1949006-distmantle-vs-disassemble.html#:~:text=Dismantle%20%2D%20to%20take%20apart.,a%20piece%20of%20machinery%20etc).) seem to agree.

Comment: Chairs and furniture are not "fitted" usually, but doors and cabinets are. So doors and cabinets can be _taken down_, but chairs or furniture would be _taken apart_.

Comment: *" Can we say we dismantle a door"* You can say that but what do you want it to mean? Do you mean that the door was removed from its position in the doorway or do you mean that door itself was broken into smaller pieces?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Exactly...the Q is unclear. Doors can only be broken down into wood, hinges and door knobs. How is furniture dismantled? Is it chopped up for firewood? Machinery is dismantled for re-cycle. I was gonna answer, but now I am  VTCing for lack of clarity.

Comment: Hello Arun....You had 2 answers, and now both off them  have been temporarily deleted for the sake of clarity.  Please provide some research, and better context.

Comment: @Cascabel Sorry for being unclear but I meant that if the door itself was broken into smaller pieces, can we use any one word or should we use words like broken into or taken apart.For example a child may ask - can the fitted pieces of wood be taken apart or pulled out to be used again - although it may not be possible - how will I explain it to him?

Comment: Hello Arun...Your post  needs  to be edited to make  your Q clear. Comments are not sufficient. I have edited the post in an attempt   to bring it into line with site standards.

Comment: @Cascabel okay and thanks for editing my question.